# Subgroups of $S_n$ that are automorphism groups of a graph with $n$ vertices.

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group

Can one find all the subgroups of $S_n$ that are automorphism group of a graph with $n$ vertices?

I know that every subgroup of $S_n$ can be the automorphism group for a graph with enough vertices via Cayley's graphs. But I can't find anything imposing the restriction that the graph must have $n$ vertices.

I know that the result is false in general, e.g. there's no graph with 3 vertices such that $Aut(G)\cong C_3$ the $3$-cycle.

I was thinking that maybe one can find conditions on the generators of the automorphism group of a graph, so maybe one can find a familiy of subgroups of $S_n$ that have the property or something like that.

Comment: Sequence [A095348](https://oeis.org/A095348) in the OEIS counts the number of different orders those groups can have. (The number of different groups, which is the sequence we'd really want, doesn't appear to be in the OEIS. The two sequences first diverge for $n=6$, when there are $15$ possible automorphism groups, but only $14$ possible orders: for order $8$, we can get both $D_4$ and $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$.)

Comment: The so-called "concrete version" of König's problem imposes an even harsher restriction: given a specific permutation group, we ask when it is the automorphism group of some graph. (This distinguishes, for example, between two subgroups of $S_9$: the one generated by $(1\;2\;3)$ and the one generated by $(1\;2\;3)\;(4\;5\;6)\;(7\;8\;9)$. Both are isomorphic to the cyclic group $C_3$, but the second one is the automorphism group of a graph while the first is not.) This is very hard, but there are some partial results.